# Testnet peers list (with IP addresses)

Tags: testnet, peers

There are some services to get the list of current known peers,
like those offered by [21.co](https://bitnodes.21.co/) or [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/ip-log)
but I can't find anything similar for the Testnet network.

Does anybody know a Testnet peer list?

Actually, it is also very hard to find any IP testnet address.
Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a testnet dns seeder.

Type this into your terminal:

```
dig A testnet-seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
```

or

```
dig A seed.tbtc.petertodd.org
```

for IPv6

```
dig AAAA testnet-seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
```